# Stop jQuery From Selecting Parents That Also Match

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to set up a responsive drop down menu that, in responsive mode, overrides the hover drops, disables the default click event for any a links that have sub ULs (so the ones that have a drop down ul menu beneath them) and expands the CHILD ul on click.

```
$('.nav ul li').click(function() {

    if( $(this).children('ul').length ) {

        if ( $(window).width() <= 980 ) { 

            event.preventDefault();

            if( $(this).children('ul:first').is(':visible') ) {
                $(this).children('ul:first').hide(); }

            else { $(this).children('ul:first').show(); }

        } 

    }

});
```

I've got it working, but what's happening is the selector is also matching all ancestors of the current li...

So if I have:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...so what is happening is that if I click item 2, it will expand the UL underneath it, BUT then it will also select the li for item 1, and hide the UL underneath it and hide it since it is currently visible.

I need it to ONLY select the UL directly underneath the li the user clicks, NOT any of its parents (because then it will start hiding everything just as the code tells it to do).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably selecting direct `>` child of a parent and stopping the event bubbling `.stopPropagation()` will work, like this:

```
$('.nav ul li').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($('> ul:first', this).is(':visible')) {
    $('> ul:first', this).hide();
  } else {
    $('> ul:first', this).show();
  }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MHSsX/)

Comment: @ChrisDeMarco Great! i am glad it helped you and also expecting a tick.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the event parameter, which you are later trying to use:

```
('.nav ul li').click(function(event) {
                                ^------------- ADD THIS
```

If preventing the event is not enough, you may need to stop propagating the event too:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```